# Symfony how to include controller on base.html.twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a small question, I'm new to symfony, I created a controller and a menu template that I want to integrate into my base.html.twig.

I absolutely need the controller to be called because I am testing to know if the session variable is empty or not.

```
    {% block menu %}
    {% include 'menu/index.html.twig' %}
    {% endblock %}
    
    <body>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
```

So I tried this (it works perfectly BUT it didn't call my controller so when I do my test on session it won't work....)

I searched but I can't include the controller instead of the template...

thanks in advance

Comment: This will help you : https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#embedding-controllers

Comment: There are no packages that allow me to handle this without having to use the symfony method? I'm guessing someone has already thought of that...

Comment: If you only want tto access the session, you can use the twig var app.session.get('vat'). If you want to have complex behavior, then contorller will be the way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Symfony, you cannot call a Controller from inside a twig, what you can do is store variables inside a Controller, and then call those variables from inside the twig.

For example, in your case, in the Controller you create your variable and save it in the session as follows:

```
//...
class BaseController extends AbstractController
{
//...

$session->set('var_i_need', 222);

return $this->render('menu/index.html.twig', [
'controller_name' => 'BaseController',
]);

}
```

Then inside the twig you get the variable:

```
{% set var_i_need = app.session.get('var_i_need') %}
```

And test if it is empty or not:

```
{% if var_i_need is not NULL %}
{% ... %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The controller shouldn't be called from a twig. EOT

You need to move your code from controller to service or helper.
Then you should run the service from controller.

Also, you need to create a new twig function and call service/helper code in this function.

This way the code form controller will be executed in twig  - in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, you can and may want to include controllers in twig for things like menus that are common to multiple pages but have no relation with controllers that act on those pages. And there is an official documentation for this here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#embedding-controllers

Tip: use caching techniques for this kind of includes.